# Jackson annotation not working with custom date serializer

Tags: java, serialization, annotations, jackson

I read the [Jackson's annotations doc](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) but I still can't find how to call a custom serializer from annotations to serialize a `java.sql.Date` object.

```
class Test {
    java.sql.Date mDate = null;

    @JsonValue("serializeDate")       //@JsonValue(DateAsTimestampSerializer.class)
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void String serializeDate(Date d) {
        return String.valueOf(d.getTime());
    }

    class DateAsTimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
    {
         @Override
         public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
              throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
             jgen.writeFieldName(String.valueOf(value.getTime()));
         }
    }
}
```

But the annotation `@JsonValue` seems to accept only a boolean as argument, as opposed to the [annotations doc](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) which states :

> @JsonValue(method): used to mark a method thats return value is to be used as serialization for the object; often used to mark String-producing methods (like toString()) to produce JSON primitive value serialization
>   Blockquote

Am I using the right annotation ? How could I return the value from the `Serializer`instead of toString() ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [JsonSerialize](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html) annotation. And yours implementation of DateSerializer contains bug. I think, want to serialize date value not name - use `writeString` method instead of `writeFieldName` method.

See my example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        a.setDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        objectMapper.writeValue(writer, a);
        System.out.println(writer);
    }
}

class A {

    @JsonSerialize(using = DateAsTimestampSerializer.class)
    private Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}

class DateAsTimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(String.valueOf(value.getTime()));
    }
}
```